# Trigger when there are 30 events in sqs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a requirement to process 30 files together from an s3 bucket.
I configured sqs for s3 object create event but my lambda is triggered every time the files comes in. I wanted to trigger the lambda only when 30 files are there .can any body help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. You need to develop a fully **custom solution** for that. For example store all events in dynanodb, and monitor it for when it gets to 30 events. Then you process them all.